# How to apply a change made in the application.properties file while the app is running?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The war file is already deployed. Then some changes need to be made in the `application.properties` file. What is the correct way to proceed for that ?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do that. If you require runtime changes to the Spring Boot configuration then you might need to have them being read from a Config Server and add `@RefreshScope` to your `@Configuration` annotated classes so that they can be reloaded at runtime. You can find more information about this at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope.